# How do I backstab someone?

Tags: fallout-4

In Fallout 4, there is a stat which counts the number of backstabs performed (at the bottom of the screen below). **What is a backstab and how do I perform one ?**

[image]

I suppose it has to do with melee attacks and sneak, but I never found how to backstab someone...

Comment: I would try sneaking up on someone and getting extra sneak attack damage with a melee weapon. You might need to be fully hidden. If that doesn't increment it, I would guess you need to have the damage enhanced by the Ninja perk. If that doesn't do it, I will be surprised.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A backstab in Fallout 4 is simply a sneak attack using a melee weapon. It doesn't have to be done from the back, though it's much more difficult to pull off from the front.

Backstabbing can be done on any character, including your companions, or robots and synths (tested on Codsworth and Valentine).

Also, it can not be done with just any weapon, though I'm not too sure which weapons do work, and which weapons don't.

---

Weapons I've tested which don't work:

- Grognak's Axe

Weapons I've tested which work:

- Power Fist
- Shishkebab
- Ripper
- Combat knife
- Chinese officer sword

Comment: This is pretty strongly implied, but just to be explicit: you've confirmed that this increments the counter on the stats page?

Comment: @DCShannon. Yes, that's also how I determined that Grognak's Axe doesn't count, but the Power Fist does. As odd as that may seem.

Comment: Does that mean you do not get sneak attack damage bonuses with Grognak's Axe or it just doesn't count as a backstab?

Comment: @Nelson. You do get the bonus damage with Grognak's Axe, but your "backstab" counter won't increase. At least, it didn't when I tested it.

Comment: Well, it seems that my new melee character (not the one of the screenshot) is sooo bad at sneaking (low level and low Agility) that I never managed to stay hidden enough until contact -_- Will have to train him ... or just go running straight to the enemy and keep bashing.

Comment: @Autar. A few things that'll help your character stay hidden: Try to wear light equipment (no armor, light clothing, light weapon), move slowly, approach only from the back, only approach enemies that are alone, use a Stealth Boy. Also keep in mind that a backstab doesn't automatically kill a character, though you can deal up to 10 times more damage with the Ninja perk maxed out.

Comment: You can also backstab by meleeing with a ranged weapon. It does a really nice rifle-butt-to-the-back-of-the-neck.

Answer (score 0):

When you go behind someone, you can power attack them which will sometimes go into a little animation of you killing them. Example: If you have a sword or a knife you will thrust into their neck. I'm not sure how to get it every time, but you usually have to be directly behind them, like in Dark Souls 3